# Unable to boot into windows after removing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

after realizing I installed the wrong Ubuntu version(20.04), I wanted to remove it and then install the correct version(18.04).

I used this guide:

https://itsfoss.com/uninstall-ubuntu-linux-windows-dual-boot/

However, steps 6 and 8 do not work for me. Therefore, I tried solutions from here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259069/how-to-start-a-windows-partition-from-the-grub-command-line

However, insmod chain throws the "Error" unsupported filesystem.

And, the approach using diskpart (from a repair usb stick) doesn't work, as step 9 (Z: dir) returns "File not found".

Could someone help me fix my Windows partition?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: It sounds like the "fix MBR" command failed in the instructions you followed.

Comment: Step 6 from the guide worked for me! I am just saying that for other people who might consider following this guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

boot from your Ubuntu live CD/ USB and follow instructions given in link of [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) page. Follow the second option:

**install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu**

- connect to the Internet
- open a new Terminal, then type the following commands (press Enter after each line):

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
> ```

And follow **Recommended repair** for more detail.

You can also refer to website of [Boot-Repair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/)

Comment: Is Windows UEFI or BIOS install? Just be sure to boot Ubuntu live installer in same boot mode and use ppa to add Boot-Repair. If still issues post link to summary report.