# Grub rescue after deleting ubuntu from dual boot. Windows 7. No live usb, installation disc or product key

Tags: grub2

I am an utter noob. I understand similar questions have been asked before. But I havent seen one where someone screwed up their live usb after deleting their ubuntu partition. Also it is a very old laptop and I have no installation disc or product key either. This laptop has Windows 7, whose ISO image is no longer available on the microsoft site. So is it possible to get back my windows? I am greeted by the grub resuce screen.

Comment: Now most systems are UEFI, so you just have to change boot order in UEFI settings to recover from deletion of Ubuntu. Always best to make sure default boot is system you want to keep before deleteing anything. And always have a repart/recovery flash drive for current version of every installed system. Since BIOS, you may be able to install a Windows type boot loader to MBR with Boot-Repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  BIOS only boots from MBR and only one boot loader can be in MBR.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *You removed the OS that is on-topic on this site, we don't support windows. You should have ensured windows controlled booting before deleting the OS that did.. but windows recovery media will fix that however we don't support windows*

Comment: Oldfred...thank you. Boot-repair worked. Guiverc my bad..thank you for letting me know about the on-topics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into windows after removing Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237077/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-removing-ubuntu-20-04)